# Python 2.7 File Writing And Function Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ok so me and my friend have been doing work on a code breaker mini game and It isn't the best code but it almost works. The code works very smoothly up until you win the game, After that there is a big error.
This is the Error Log:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "E:\cod3breaker\cod3breaker programe.py", line 219, in <module>
start(0,0,0,0,1,0)
File "E:\cod3breaker\cod3breaker programe.py", line 141, in start
start(create,code,attempts,cracks,stage,points)
File "E:\cod3breaker\cod3breaker programe.py", line 145, in start
start(create,code,attempts,cracks,stage,points)
File "E:\cod3breaker\cod3breaker programe.py", line 174, in start
file.writelines(cracks)
TypeError: writelines() requires an iterable argument
```

As of what I can see the start Function isn't working like it should, At the beginning of the code the function is:

```
def start(create,code,attempts,cracks,stage,points):
```

Also the other error is about writelines. I don't have any idea why that doesn't work:

```
file.writelines(cracks)
```

I'm sorry for asking such a stupid question and not spending time researching it myself first. Although I cant return your wasted time I can apologize for it.

Comment: what is cracks? can you show type(cracks)?

Comment: Its the number of times the code has been cracked ( Guessed)

Comment: So is cracks a int?
The error log suggests that writelines() requires an iterable argument https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_writelines.htm.

So you probably want to use file.write or otherwise convert the int to a sequence, like:  file.writelines(["Number of cracks = %d"%cracks])

Comment: it didn't work so heres the code

Comment: int(points)
points = points + won
file = open("savedata\points.txt", "w+")
file.writelines("points = %d"%points)
file.close()

Comment: you forgot the square brackets to create a list (a sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writelines() requires an iterable of strings (docs: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_writelines.htm)

In your case you are passing an int, which is not iterable (as explained in the Error Log).
So you have two choices:

- Use file.write, which accepts single entries
- Wrap your string in a list to use file.writelines

and in both cases you need to convert the integer to string.

Method 1:

```
points = 10    
file = open(r"H:\Python_Scripts\test.txt", "w+")  # Change path
file.write("points = %d"%points)
file.close()
```

Method 2:

```
points = 10    
file = open(r"H:\Python_Scripts\test.txt", "w+") # Change path
file.writelines(["points = %d"%points])
file.close()
```